# Как при нажатии кнопки добавлять поля в массив?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть некий массив с данными, также есть форма с полями, как при нажатии на кнопку "добавить" поля перенести в массив? HTML:

```
<legend>Добавить студента</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="surname">Фамилия</label>
                    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" size="12" tabindex="1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Имя</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="middle_name">Отчество</label>
                    <input type="text" name="middle_name" id="middle_name" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="facultet">Факультет</label>
                    <input type="text" name="facultet" id="facultet" value="" size="12" tabindex="3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <label for="borned">Дата рождения</label>
                <input type="date" name="borned" id="borned" value="" size="12" tabindex="3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="start_sudy">Год начала обучения</label>
                    <input type="number" name="start_sudy" id="start_sudy" value="" size="12" tabindex="3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button name="MyButton" id="MyButton" value="Добавить">Добавить</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Массив: `const arr_info = [ {surname: 'Арзамасцев', name: 'Николай', middle_name: 'Николаевич', bornded: '03.03.2001', start_study: '2019', fac: 'Информатика и вычислительная техника' } ]`

````
{
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    let middle_name = document.getElementById('middle_name').value;
    let date_borned = document.getElementById('borned').value;
    let start_sudy = document.getElementById('start_sudy').value;
    let fac = document.getElementById('facultet').value;
    arr_info.push(surname[0])
    arr_info.push(middle_name[2])
    arr_info.push(start_sudy[4])
    arr_info.push(fac[5])

}```

Также пробовал через обработчик клика функцию вызвать - не работает
````

Comment: Ну хорошо, делайте. Как? Кодом.

Comment: Приведите хотя бы попытку, что Вы попытались сделать?

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить. что именно вы пытались запушить в конец массива, и почему? У вас массив получает данные и выходит такое: `[{%ваш_объект%},%0-й_символ_фамилии%,%2-й_символ_отчества%,%4-й_символ_даты_который_не_работает%,%5-й_символ_факультета%]`.

Comment: я попытался запушить туда введенные данные в строке input